# Django model, ImportError attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, django

I'm making a small Django app, and i just want to make some tests over the QuerySet of my model. However, when running code outside the manage.py runserver environment, i get this error :

```
from .models import Article
```

Error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

As already said, this works perfectly when making views, i can import my Article model and create Articles from the admin dashboard.

My app structure looks like this:

```
app/
  admin.py
  apps.py
  models.py (this contains my Article model)
  views.py
  file_where_ihave_my_error.py
  __init__.py
```

Comment: are you running this app on command line, or on development server?

Comment: Hi, i'm running it over SublimeText

Comment: do you have __ init __.py somewhere? Please check the needed structure here : https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/django-project-structure-layout/

Comment: yes sir, i have a ```__init__.py``` on the app/ folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

Django accepts `from .models import *model_name*`, but when you try to run the file as any other Python app, you'd get such an error.
to solve it, you either need to user `from models import *model_name*`, or run Django server `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Thanks, this kinda worked since i'm getting another error : ```django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.```

What is the most user friendly way to get around this?

Comment: then the only solution is to run server... it's not a good practice to run a Django app as a regular Python app

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can i test code, navigate through a list of ```mymodel.objects.all()``` etc ?

Comment: please start a new question for this and add some of your code so we can answer it

Comment: You can set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to the `path/to/settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

When I have this issue on Flask or Django, I usually do my relative imports as bellow, and once debugg is complete I reset back to the normal way of doing imports with Django:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from models import Article 
else: 
    from .models import Article
```

Basically depending of wether you launch your code from Python using main or from the Django server, it will select the correct way to handle your imports.

And when you want to launch your code from Python you add at the end of your code "if **name** == '**main**':" with then your code to run:

```
from typing import List
# other imports
# Your article import
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from models import Article 
else: 
    from .models import Article
# Your code

def my_code_to_run():
    article=Article()

# Your main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_code_to_run()
```

Note that if you are calling Databases that are setup in settings.py of Django the call will not work as the connections won't be defined...